# Calling variables, dynamically

Tags: templating, variable, concatenation

I've got a parent template which contains the following code:

```
{% include '_layout' with {'countryCode': 'au'} %}
```

I have a global set with the handle `au_Variables`, and within that a field with the handle `vimeoVideoId_au`

The problem I'm having is with trying to render the following global: `{{ au_Variables.vimeoVideoId_au }}` dynamically, using the countryCode.

I've tried

```
{% set videoId = countryCode~'_Variables.vimeoVideoId_'~countryCode %}
```

And then outputting `{{ videoId }}` but all I get is the string `au_Variables.vimeoVideoId_au`, not the rendered global.

Any ideas how to do this in Twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a bit of a workaround, not sure if it's the best way to do it.

I restructured my fields, turns I don't need unique field names for the globals (still thinking in EE mode) so that took away half the problem.

I can access the global group dynamically, using [_context](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables)

So after renaming my Video ID field, I can call the global set dynamically using:

```
{{ _context[countryCode~'_Variables'].vimeoId }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you saw this, but you may also be able to use the Twig `attribute` function:

```
{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

Pretty straightforward, here's [the official docs page...](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

Comment: Thanks. it was the property being dynamic too which was causing me to have all sorts of issues.

Comment: Noting here an application of this function because it was not 'straightforward' to me until I hit upon the solution by trial and error! In my case the variable is the **Globals field handle**, so I've ended up with `{{ attribute(globalSetHandle, globalsFieldVariable') }}`, which works a treat.