# nesting variables in twig

Tags: templating

I have 3 sets of globals, which use the same fields handles.

```
{{ firstGlobalHandle.aFieldHandle }}
{{ secondGlobalHandle.aFieldHandle }}
{{ thirdGlobalHandle.aFieldHandle }}
```

In a child template, I set a variable corresponding to the handle of the global group which I need to call

```
{% set globalHandle = "secondGlobalHandle" %}
```

Now in the In the parent template, I would like to do the following :

```
{{ '{{ globalHandle }}'.aFieldHandle }}
```

Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, my bad, this was answered [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/703/calling-variables-dynamically?rq=1)

Here is the solution :

```
{{ _context[ globalHandle ].aFieldHandle }}
```